# reading stdin in shell

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdin

```
#!/bin/sh
#myVar=`date`#case 1
#myVar=`cat /dev/stdin`#case 2
myVar=($(< /dev/stdin)) #case 3
echo $myVar
exit 2
```

case 1 works
case 2 and 3 don't work. 
When I test with either 2 or 3; there is no output and the script never exits

What I eventually require is to read from the stdin written to by the postfix pipe

Comment: Calling a script with /bin/sh does not make it a bash script.

Comment: Please fix your question to be more specific about what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
read fred
echo $fred
```

Comment: I want to read multiple lines !

Comment: You should probably have said so, then.  Do you want to read them to one variable, or many?  More precision in the question will get you more functionality in the answers!

Comment: @Stewie `while read line ; do echo $line ; done`

Comment: @MadHatter I had written that "What I eventually require is to read from the stdin written to by the postfix pipe" which would explain that the data will span multiple lines, but I guess it wasn't enough and I'll take care next time :) Anyway initializing as bin/bash instead of bin/sh solved it thanks